# Swift Class: Bank - Creating a Banking Application

Tags: swift

This is an assessment question, I need help with:
"
Create a Banking Application with a code containing:

- Customer Class with :

  1. ID:Int
  2. name:String
  3. balance:Double attributes
- Bank class with

  1. Customer array attribute
  2. Constructor which receives count as parameter, and dynamically builds the customer array based on count:

     1. On Creation, minimum balance of 500 should be assigned to the customer.
     2. Customer ID must start from 1, and should increment by 1.
     3. `deposit(id:Int, amount:Double)->Void` to deposit amount to ID.
     4. `withdraw(id:Int,amount:Double)->Void` to withdraw from ID(maintain minimum balance of 500)
     5. `getCustomer(ID:Int)->`Returns Customer of specified ID, nil otherwise.

The code I got so far:

```
import Foundation

/* Editable Code */
class Customer{
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var balance:Double
    init(id:Int,name:String,balance:Double){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        if(self.balance <= 0){
            self.balance = 500
        } else {
            self.balance = balance
        }
    }
}
class Bank: Customer{
    // create customer array with name customers
    var customers:Array = [
        Customer(id:123,name:"Ben",balance:12340.00),
        Customer(id:124,name:"Tom",balance:12350.00),
        Customer(id:125,name:"Jerry",balance:12389.90)
    ]
    var count:Int = 1
    init(count:Int){
        self.count = count
    }
    //implement deposit, withdraw , and getCustomer
    func deposit(id:Int,amount:Double) -> Void {
        if(balance >= 0){
            balance = balance + amount
        }
    }
    func withdraw(id:Int,amount:Double) -> Void {
        if amount > 0.0 {
            if balance - amount >= 500.0 {
                balance = balance - amount
            }
        }
    }
    func getCustomer(id:Int) -> Customer {
        if(Customer[id] == id){
            return Customer
        }
    }
}
/*End of Editable Code*/
/*Uneditable Code from Here*/
let stdout = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: stdout, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: stdout)!

guard let custCount = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
    else { fatalError("Bad input") }

guard let testCaseCount = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
    else { fatalError("Bad input") }

var bank = Bank(count:custCount)

guard let id = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
    else { fatalError("Bad input") }

for _ in 1...testCaseCount {
    guard let ops = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
        else { fatalError("Bad input") }

    guard let amount = Double((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
        else { fatalError("Bad input") }

    switch ops{
    case 1 ://deposit
        bank.deposit(id:id,amount:amount)
    case -1 : //withdraw
        bank.withdraw(id:id,amount:amount)
    default : break

    }
}



let cust:Customer! = bank.getCustomer(id:id)
fileHandle.write(String(bank.customers.count).data(using: .utf8)!)
fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

if cust != nil {
    fileHandle.write(String(cust.balance).data(using: .utf8)!)
}
```

Part I am struggling is Customer Array Attribute above.

Need pointers on how to create the above said Customer array attribute

Please let me know how to modify my code to get achieve the above requirement.
Any help on this is much appreciated.

**UPDATE 2)** Added the solution in here, as it was closed by few, who thought I did not ask right question:

Used Bradley Mackey hint and worked on this solution.
**Solution**

```
import Foundation
/* Editable Code */

class Bank: Customer{
    // create customer array with name customers
    var customers:[Customer]
    /*var customers:Array = [
     Customer(id:1,name:"Ben",balance:12340.00),
     Customer(id:2,name:"Tom",balance:12350.00),
     Customer(id:3,name:"Jerry",balance:12389.90)
     ]*/
    var count:Int = 0
    init(count:Int){
        NSLog("C: \(count)")
        self.count = count
        customers = []
        var id:Int = 1
        var name:String = ""
        var balance:Double = 500.00
        for i in 1...count {
            id = i
            customers.append(Customer(id:id,name:name,balance:balance))
        }
        super.init(id:id,name:name,balance:balance)
    }
    //implement deposit, withdraw , and getCustomer
    func deposit(id:Int,amount:Double) -> Void {
        NSLog("Deposit init: \(id) \(amount) \(count)")
        if(id > count){
            NSLog("\(id) > \(count)")
        }
        if(id == count){
            customers[id-1].balance = customers[id-1].balance + amount
            NSLog("\(id) = \(count) balance after deposit is \(customers[id-1].balance)")
        }
        if(id < count) {
            for i in 1...id{
                NSLog("for deposit \(i) \(customers[i-1].id)")
                if(customers[i-1].id == id){
                    customers[i-1].balance = customers[i-1].balance + amount
                    NSLog("\(i)")
                }
            }
            NSLog("\(id) < \(count) balance after deposit is \(customers[id].balance)")
        }
        NSLog("deposit last \(id)  \(amount)")
    }
    func withdraw(id:Int,amount:Double) -> Void {
        NSLog("withdraw: \(id) \(amount)")
        if(id <= count){
            for i in 1...id{
                if(customers[i-1].id == id){
                    if((customers[i-1].balance - amount) > 500){
                        customers[i-1].balance = customers[i-1].balance - amount
                        NSLog("withdraw made \(amount) on  \(i-1)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        NSLog("withdraw \(id) \(amount)")
    }
    func getCustomer(id:Int) -> Customer? {
        NSLog("getcus \(id)")
        /*if(id == 1){
         return customers[id]
         }*/
        if(id > count){
            return nil
        }
        if(id == count){
            return customers[id-1]
        }
        if(id < count){
            for i in 0...id {
                if(customers[i].id == id){
                    return customers[i]
                }
            }
        }
        NSLog("Bal: \(customers[id].balance)")
        return nil
    }
}

/*End of Editable Code*/
/*Uneditable Code from Here*/
let stdout = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: stdout, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: stdout)!

guard let custCount = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
else { fatalError("Bad input") }

guard let testCaseCount = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
else { fatalError("Bad input") }

var bank = Bank(count:custCount)

guard let id = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
    else { fatalError("Bad input") }

for _ in 1...testCaseCount {
    guard let ops = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
    else { fatalError("Bad input") }

    guard let amount = Double((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
    else { fatalError("Bad input") }

   switch ops{
       case 1 ://deposit
                bank.deposit(id:id,amount:amount)
       case -1 : //withdraw
                bank.withdraw(id:id,amount:amount)
       default : break

   }
}



let cust:Customer! = bank.getCustomer(id:id)
fileHandle.write(String(bank.customers.count).data(using: .utf8)!)
fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

if cust != nil {
fileHandle.write(String(cust.balance).data(using: .utf8)!)
}
```

Comment: Did the solution work? One test case out of 4 is always failing.

Comment: You can use  enumerated for loop :

func deposit(id:Int,amount:Double) -> Void {
        for (index, customer) in customers.enumerated() {
            if customer.id == id {
                customer.balance += amount
                customers[index] = customer
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

I'll give some general hints as this is an assessment.

The *customer array attribute* refers to this property on the `Bank`.

```swift
var customers:Array = [
        Customer(id:123,name:"Ben",balance:12340.00),
        Customer(id:124,name:"Tom",balance:12350.00),
        Customer(id:125,name:"Jerry",balance:12389.90)
    ]
```

You will need to set this to be some customers that is passed to the `init` 'initializer' as it's called in Swift. To do this, use a FOR LOOP to figure out how many customers you need, then create a customer in each one, and `append` each one to the array. For example:

```swift
init(count:Int){
    self.count = count

    // first of all, clear the customers array
    customers = []


    for i in 1...count {
        // CREATE THE CUSTOMER HERE
        // ...
        // use i as the customer id to create each customer, 
        // setting their initial balance to 500, then `append` to `customers`
    }
}
```